# Append div, when specific text appears in element. Return it to original location when specific text disappears

Tags: jquery, html

I want to move a div to another location when specific text in a span element appears. And move it back to original location and hide it when that specific text disappears.

I have almost achieved this functionality with the code below, however there is one problem, the triggertext can appear/disappear several times and the code I'm using creates many copies of the div that I want to move. Each time the triggertext appears, a new copy of the div that I want to move appears.

```
$(".add-documents, .document-list").hide();

$('.docu').change(function(){
    if ($(".docu .container span:contains('triggertext')").length) {
        $(".add-documents, .document-list").show();
        $(".add-documents, .document-list").appendTo(".docu");
    } else {
        $(".add-documents, .document-list").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Try, $(".add-documents, .document-list").detach().appendTo(".docu");

Comment: Unfortunately it still adds multiple elements.

Comment: To clarify, is it adding the copy once for each instance of 'triggertext' in the span or each time the 'triggertext' is removed and then typed in again?

Comment: Oh, wait. Why do you have a comma in ".add-documents, .document-list"? That's going to tell it to add the div under each element with class add-documents and each element with class document-list. I think you may just want a space there and no comma.